# Git: see many branches in a single view

Tags: git, git-branch

Is there any way to see changes from many branches in Git in a single view. For example if my project consists of scripts part and C code part, can I have them on two separate branches but still see all changes in a single view?

Comment: please explain what you consider as a "view"

Comment: I think the OP has two branches with completely different files in them, and wants to have a working tree that shows the contents of both branches at the same time. If that's the case, a simple `git merge` will suffice, as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answers! What I meant as a "view" was to see changes from both branches in the working tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create such a "view", simply create a third branch and *merge* the branches you care about:

```
git checkout -b view branch1
git merge branch2
# now 'view' sees contents of both branches
```

`view` will only show the branch contents at the time of its creation. To update the view, simply add the new merged content:

```
git checkout view           # switch to the view
git merge branch1 branch2   # ...and merge the new branch contents
```

If the file names in the branches are disjoint, the merges should never have conflicts. If there are conflicts on common files (such as `README`), they will be trivially resolved, and their resolution confined to (and remembered by) the `view` branch.

The same logic applies with more than two branches, as the `merge` command accepts an arbitrary number of branches to merge.